# Editing state inside a modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Im making a little note taking application. When the user writes their title and note and clicks submit the note get placed on the page... I want to be able to edit the note. When the edit button is clicked, a modal pops up and I want the users title and note to be inside the input boxes in the modal.

Here is an image for a better understanding.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cFSh.png

I want the title and the note to be inside the input boxes, allowing the user to edit them. Below is my modal component, and the function I wrote below is working perfectly but its not "editing" the original title or note, its basically just making a new one.

Any idea how I can get the title and note in the modal input boxes and just directly modify them as needed? Thanks in advance!

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Modal({
  title,
  note,
  setCompletedNote,
  FullNote,
  setIsModalShown,
  ...props
}) {
  const [newTitle, setNewTitle] = useState("");
  const [newNote, setNewNote] = useState("");

  function editNoteCompleted(id, newTitle, newNote, e) {
    setCompletedNote((prevState) =>
      prevState.map((n) => {
        if (n.id === id) {
          return { ...n, title: newTitle, note: newNote }; 
        }
        return n; 
      })
    );

    setIsModalShown(false);
  }

  return (
    <div className="modal__container">
      <div className="modal__note-information">
        <p>Edit Note:</p>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="newTitle"
          value={newTitle}
          onChange={(e) => setNewTitle(e.target.value)}
        />
        <br />
        <input
          type="text"
          value={newNote}
          name="newNote"
          onChange={(e) => setNewNote(e.target.value)}
        />

        <div className="modal__button-container">
          <button
            className="modal__ok-button"
            onClick={() => editNoteCompleted(FullNote.id, newTitle, newNote)}
          >
            Ok
          </button>
          <button className="modal__cancel-button">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the title and note of the selected component is passed as props . Then you just need to have the initialValue of your state to be the `title` and `note` prop.

```
export default function Modal({
  title, 
  note,
  setCompletedNote,
  FullNote,
  setIsModalShown,
  ...props
}) {
  const [newTitle, setNewTitle] = useState(title || ''); 
  const [newNote, setNewNote] = useState(note || '');
```

Comment: Hello Shyam,
The only problem with this approach is if you edit a note title, and try to go back and edit an already existing note.. the initial title is display as the first note title that you edited. Does this make sense? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thats why in the answer i have mentioned as `selected component` .  But looks like you have a common modal . If that is the case then you need to have a separate state for the Selected note . And pass the selected notes title and note to the modal . So the flow goes like this -> click on the edit of the note -> set this note as the selected note -> open the modal .  Another approach would be to just have the modal moved inside your note component so each note will have their own modal and will not be aware of the other note .

Comment: awesome. That makes perfect sense.. ill see what I can do here. I appreciate it.

Comment: note sure why this is not working
  const editNote = (FullNote) => {
    setSelectedNote((prevState) =>({...prevState, title: FullNote.title, note: FullNote.note}))
    setIsModalShown(true);
  };



after, I am passing selectedNote to my modal and making the initial state of the newTitle and newNote the selected note like so:
  const [newTitle, setNewTitle] = useState(selectedNote.title);
  const [newNote, setNewNote] = useState(selectedNote.note);